# Matching array1 value with array2 key, output matched array2 value

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to do the following:

```
$array1 = array( "two" => "2", "three" => "3")

$array2 = array("two", "three", "four")
```

I want to match `array2`'s value with `array1`'s key.  Upon matching, I want to output `array1`'s value.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried, and the errors/problems you encountered.

Comment: And your expected output also?

Comment: It should be a simple loop over `array2`'s values.

Comment: [array_intersect_key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) could be a useful function here; perhaps used with [array_flip()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) on your second array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mark Baker commented, you can use `array_flip()` together with `array_intersect_key()`

```
$array1 = array( "two" => "2", "three" => "3");

$array2 = array("two", "three", "four");
$array2 = array_flip($array2);

print_r(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2) );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array( "two" => "2", "three" => "3");
foreach($array1 as $key=>$val){
    $array_1[] = $key;
}
$array2 = array("two", "three", "four");


$result = array_diff($array2, $array_1);

print_r($result);
```